# Do matrices have average and fluctuations?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, abstract-algebra, matrices, statistics

Given a set of numbers, one can calculate the average of those numbers and the fluctuation (variance) over the average. E.g,, $\langle A \rangle=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=0}^N A_i$ and $(\delta A)^2 = \langle A^2 \rangle - \langle A \rangle^2$.

Now, suppose there is a set of matrices with the same type ($3\times 3$, Hermitian, etc.), are there concepts like the average of matrices and the fluctuation of matrices (over their average)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is called quantum mechanics! If v is a unit vector then 
$\left\langle v,Av \right\rangle ={{v}^{T}}Av$ has all the properties of an average and $\left\langle v,A^2v \right\rangle -\left\langle v,Av \right\rangle^2$ is a fluctuation. Clearly, these properties are dependent upon the "state" v and different staes create different notions of average.