# Is there a notion of an ``average'' of a set of linear operators?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition, lie-groups

Say we have a set of (invertible) linear operators 
$ \{ A, B, C \}$. Is there any meaningful sense in which we could conceive of an ``average'' of these linear operators?

It would seem like the easy first answer would be some version of geometric mean, but for the fact that operators do not commute.

Another idea I thought about would be some (invertible) $D$ s.t. for $A' := A D^{-1}$, $B' := B D^{-1}$, and $C' := C D^{-1}$ we have $A' B' C' = I$, but again I can't see how this works given that operators don't commute.

I believe this question was asked previously here:

[Do matrices have average and fluctuations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280309/do-matrices-have-average-and-fluctuations)

But I don't think the response really answered the OP's question.

Comment: Why geometric? What is the average of the three image vectors $Ax$, $Bx$, $Cx$? Well, $\frac 1 3 (Ax + Bx + Cx)$ is one. But that's the image of $\frac 1 3 (A + B + C)$. So is that sensible average of these three operators? Or do you have any particular reason for preferring a "multiplicative" one?

Comment: Operator spaces are Banach spaces. You can put probability measures on Banach spaces, e.g. Gaussian ones, and average over them.

Comment: Thank you for these good points!